# Comparing strings in python to find errors

Tags: python, string-comparison

I have a string that is the correct spelling of a word:

```
FOO
```

I would allow someine to mistype the word in such ways:

```
FO, F00, F0O ,FO0
```

Is there a nice way to check for this ? Lower case should also be seen as correct, or convert to upper case. What ever would be the prettiest.

Comment: Conversion to lower case can be done with the [str.lower() function](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower).  Similarly, there is the [str.upper() function](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) if that's what you want.

Comment: you need to precisely define what kind of mistypings you allow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The builtin module difflib has a [get_close_matches](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) function.

You can use it like this:

```
>>> import difflib
>>> difflib.get_close_matches('FO', ['FOO', 'BAR', 'BAZ'])
['FOO']
>>> difflib.get_close_matches('F00', ['FOO', 'BAR', 'BAZ'])
[]
>>> difflib.get_close_matches('F0O', ['FOO', 'BAR', 'BAZ'])
['FOO']
>>> difflib.get_close_matches('FO0', ['FOO', 'BAR', 'BAZ'])
['FOO']
```

Notice that it doesn't match one of your cases. You could lower the `cutoff` parameter to get a match:

```
>>> difflib.get_close_matches('F00', ['FOO', 'BAR', 'BAZ'], cutoff=0.3)
['FOO']
```

Answer (score 6):

One approach is to calculate the [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) between the strings. You can for example use the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), or invent your own distance function that considers 0 and O more close than 0 and P, for example.

Another is to transform each word into a canonical form, and compare canonical forms. You can for example convert the string to uppercase, replace all 0s with Os, 1s with Is, etc., then remove duplicated letters.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> def canonical_form(s):
        s = s.upper()
        s = s.replace('0', 'O')
        s = s.replace('1', 'I')
        s = ''.join(k for k, g in itertools.groupby(s))
        return s
>>> canonical_form('FO')
'FO'
>>> canonical_form('F00')
'FO'
>>> canonical_form('F0O')
'FO'
```

Comment: How do you determine what would be a good enough edit distance ?

Comment: That's what I want to know as well :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the 're' module

```
re.compile(r'f(o|0)+',re.I) #ignore case
```

you can use curly braces to limit the number of occurrences too. you can also get 'fancy' and define your 'leet' sets and add them in w/ %s

as in:

```
ay = '(a|4|$)'
oh = '(o,0,\))'
re.compile(r'f%s+' % (oh),re.I)
```